# @font-face Not Working in Chrome on Mac OS X

Tags: css, macos, .htaccess, google-chrome, font-face

I've been banging my head on this for half an hour. If you're on a Macintosh and you go to http://successfool.com/ in any browser other than Chrome, you'll see that our custom font loads just fine.

But if you open the console (CMD + OPTION + J), the font magically loads properly. It's as if the resource isn't loading until you open the console, then it decides to load.

I've tried this .htaccess trick at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16715684/1591507 to none avail.

On my end, this problem does NOT exist in Chrome on Windows, nor Chrome on iOS. It's exclusively on Mac OS X.

Any ideas what's going on? It's super weird....

Comment: Latest Chrome (33.0.1750.149) on OS X 10.9.2 showing identical fonts to Latest Firefox (27.0.1). I did not open the console. FireFontFamily says alejandroreyesregular is the font being used to render h1-h6 tags. I know web fonts can be a fickle beast. Perhaps a caching issue?

Comment: Interesting. My friend and I are in two different states and we're seeing the same problem. Might have to go with a different, more standardized, font. Appreciate the help.