# @font-face not rendering correct font-family in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I have a dropdownlist that contains a list of fonts  . I am able to display them properly on Firefox .. but when i turn to Chrome , the effect is not applied .

The CSS --

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Comic Sans MS !important;
    src: url('../fonts/Comic Sans MS Regular/comic.ttf');
}
```

The Dropdownlist Change  function is

```
$fontsDropdown = $('.custom-text-font').find('.fpd-fonts-dropdown').change(function() {
                    if (currentElement != null)
                    {
                        currentElement.setFontFamily(this.value);
                        currentElement.params.font = this.value;
                        //changed text to bold
                        currentElement.setFontStyle('bold');
                        currentElement.params.fontStyle = 'bold';

                        _outOfContainment(currentElement);
                        stage.renderAll();
                    }
            })
```

This produces a proper output on firefox ,,,, but on Chrome .,, It does not . Actually I get the changes reflected on Chrome .. but that change is reflected only when I click the font in dropdown second time. It does not happen on the first click on a font from the dropdown list.

Thanks

Comment: Font faces need different declarations for different browsers.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051826/font-face-with-wrong-mime-type-in-chrome

Comment: And sometimes cross-domain not allowed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641427/font-face-not-working-on-chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Comic Sans MS !important;
    src: url('../fonts/Comic Sans MS Regular/comic.ttf');
}
```

For this question.
First of all remove spaces b/w folder name like replace another name to `Comic Sans MS Regular`.
and for the font family you can choose another name than `font-family: Comic Sans MS !important;`
And remove `!important` for this..
If this is working then good otherwise you can choose..
font face generator.
You can choose font here and you can get font- face web kit.

http://convertfonts.com/

http://everythingfonts.com/font-face

Answer (score 0):

if the fonts are available in other different format(woff,ttf,svg,otf) .I suggest writing all the cross browser compatibly in the following manner

```
 src: url("DejaWeb-Bol.eot") format('embedded-opentype'), 
 url('DejaWeb-Bol.woff') format('woff'),
 url('DejaWeb-Bol.ttf') format('truetype'),
 url('DejaWeb-Bolsvg#') format('svg');
 font-weight:bold;
font-style:normal;
```

if you do't have this type of format [download here](http://www.google.com/fonts/)
 and [convert her](http://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-eot)