# @font-face works on local server but not on production server - how to debug?

Tags: fonts, font-face, font-awesome

My fonts were displaying perfectly in my local server using @font-your-face with any browser, but after uploading it to the production site (https://kenverse.com), the fonts won't load in Chrome, FF or IE10, but it loads perfectly in Torch and Safari.

While viewing page source, I see that @import url("{filepath}" was correctly called. When I've pasted the url into the address bar I see that the files are there, along with the fonts.

Firebug tells me that the fonts are loaded

GET fontawesome-webfont.woff

200 OK

So does google chrome

fontawesome-webfont.woff
www.kenverse.com/sites/kenverse.com/files/fontyourface/local_fonts/Font_Awesome-normal-normal
GET 200
OK

Please help me with his problem, thank you! Im using Drupal CMS, and the drupal SE people asked me to move the topic over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding the following code to my .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://mysite.com"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

credits to the first answer at [@font-face not working on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641427/font-face-not-working-on-chrome/16715684). Thank you so much.